# Running qsub with anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, pbs, qsub

I have a program that usually runs inside a conda environmet in Linux, because I use it to manage my libraries, with this instructions:

```
source activate my_environment
python hello_world.py
```

How can I run *hello_world.py* in a high computer that works with PBS. Instructions explains to run adapting the code *script.sh*, shown below, and calling with the instruction *qsub*.

```
# script.sh
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -S /bin/sh
#PBS -N job_example
#PBS -l select=24
#PBS -j oe
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
mpiexec ./programa_mpi
```

How do I run hello_world.py with qsub using my anaconda environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to load the Python module before activating your environment and before running your script.

```
module load python3

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
source activate my_environment

mpiexec python hello_world.py
```

Check the documentation for your institution regarding their Python modules. At my institution, Anaconda was the environment module for Python3, so you could load it as I have shown.

Comment: what do you mean by python module?

Comment: @Ghanem, I mean `module load python3`. On supercomputers, Python isn't enabled automatically, so you need to enable the version of Python or Matlab or whatever in your PBS script. Loading that module makes that version of Python your default when your Python script is run.

Comment: Ok, @HS-nebula , could have a look here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56871054/force-shell-to-use-python-from-conda-variable-in-sungrid-engine` , I have a similar issue.

Comment: @Ghanem can you reformat your comment so that it's a link? I can try, but I've never user SunGrid Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is in the environment by default, one also needs to "load" conda as well, inside the SGE(qsub) script (similar thing would hold for a slurm script too I assume). For example I had installed conda to the directory seen below in the SGE script, so I export the path (if conda is installed as a module on an HPCC, then simply load that instead):

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -q compute
#$ -l compute
#$ -cwd
#$ -N name
#$ -j yes

export PATH=$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH

source activate my_environment

environment function code...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your really need **your conda** environment you can activate it in the script

```
source ~/.bashrc #configures your shell to use conda activate
conda activate your_env_name
```

Answer (score 0):

source ~/.bashrc

conda activate your_environment

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR