# Force shell to use python from conda variable in SunGrid engine

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, sungridengine

I'm trying to execute a python file in SunGrid engine, and I'm executing it from my anaconda3 environment variable.

my code is simple:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import urllib3
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hellooo')
```

I'm calling it like:

```
qsub -V -b n -cwd -pe mp 3 playground.py
```

but I am getting this error:

```
from: can't read /var/mail/__future__
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/358.
/var/spool/gridengine/execd/cluster-rp-02/job_scripts/22924: 3: /var/spool/gridengine/execd/cluster-rp-02/job_scripts/22924: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I looked online for the error and I found a solution her: [Getting Python error “from: can't read /var/mail/Bio”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069816/getting-python-error-from-cant-read-var-mail-bio)

it proposed to add: `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the beginning of the python code.

I'm using anaconda3 where the destination of the used python is not the same. So, it should be: `#!../anaconda3/envs/py3/bin/python`

But when I add this script I get this error:

```
/home/master/bin/sge_mp_startup.sh: 10: exec: /var/spool/gridengine/execd/cluster-rp-01/job_scripts/22926: not found
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Documentation: [How to submit a job using qsub](http://bioinformatics.mdc-berlin.de/intro2UnixandSGE/sun_grid_engine_for_beginners/how_to_submit_a_job_using_qsub.html) and [`qsub` man page](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html)

Comment: @wjandrea, nothing there related to this issue.

Comment: Not directly no, but they explain how `qsub` works, which is helpful for other readers. And you might find some useful info there yourself.

Comment: Why are you using `__future__`? You're using Python 3 and from what I understand [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075082/what-is-future-in-python-used-for-and-how-when-to-use-it-and-how-it-works), it's unnecessary and seems to be causing your error.

Comment: @HS-nebula , it was in my sample code before. Anyway, also after deleting it I get the same erro.

Comment: @HS-nebula `__future__` is irrelevant here. The actual problem is that the Python script is being interpreted by a shell. See the linked question.

Comment: @Ghanem I just noticed you didn't try putting the absolute path of the `python` executable in the shebang. Try that.

Comment: @wjandrea The first error looked like it had issues with import future, which is why I asked. And good comment, I just noticed that as well

Comment: @wjandrea , what do you mean by shebang?

Comment: @Ghanem the first line, which starts with `#!`

Comment: but this is my problem! I already mentioned that I added it like: `#!../anaconda3/envs/py3/bin/python`, or do you mean another thing?

Comment: @Ghanem Let me rephrase: try putting the absolute path of the `python` executable in the shebang. I.e. replace the `../`.

Comment: @wjandrea I tried it like: `#!/home/bghanem/anaconda3/envs/py3/bin/python` , but it returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

From the linked question:

> If your script is stored in a file named script.py, you have to execute it as `python script.py`

So you could add `../anaconda3/envs/py3/bin/python` to the command line:

```
qsub -V -b n -cwd -pe mp 3 ../anaconda3/envs/py3/bin/python playground.py
```

Or if `../anaconda3/envs/py3/bin/python` is the first `python` executable in your path, you could simplify:

```
qsub -V -b n -cwd -pe mp 3 python playground.py
```

Comment: for the first script: Unable to run job: `Script length does not match declared length
Exiting`. And for the second: `Unable to read script file because of error: error opening python: No such file or directory.`

Comment: @Ghanem I don't have any experience with `qsub`, so I have no idea what it's doing.

Comment: @Ghanem maybe you need to remove the `-cwd` option?

Comment: @Ghanem Or switch `-b n` for `-b y`?

Comment: I tried to remove `-cwd` but it doesn't work. Also I tried to switch to `-b y`, I got: `/home/master/bin/sge_mp_startup.sh: 10: exec: playground.py: not found`